# ios - how can I see the NSLog statements while testing on a device in production mode?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

Is there a way I can see my NSLog statements while testing the distribution version of the app on a device which is connected via a usb?

I recall there is a way to turn the debug on, but I don't remember where that setting is, or whether that is actually the way to do it.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go the the Organizer window in Xcode (Window menu or Cmd-Shift-2). There select your device. You can see its console output, including your app's output while the app is running. Your logs will be mixed with others (from the system), though.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode Organisor Console you can see. Check out this image.

XCODE: WINDOW - Organisor - Console

[image]